# What is the best practice to enable the user to view certain categories on a portfolio page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, categories, portfolio

Here I have a portfolio page of 4 categories, when you first land on the page you will see all of them. BUT you have the option to chose form the menu which category to only show and hide all the rest.

```
<div class="wrapperA">
    <div class="contentB">
        <div id="portfolio-topSection">
            <a href="#" class="categoryButton-All">All</a>    
            <a href="#" class="categoryButton-VisualIdentity">Visual Identity</a>   
            <a href="#" class="categoryButton-Photography">Photography</a>      
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapperB">
    <div class="content">
        <div id="portfolio-gallerySection">
        <div class="grid">
            <div class="itemWrapper categoryAll">
                <a href="index.html"><img alt="" src="assets/images/me.png"></a>
                <span><p>Click To View Project</p></span>
            </div>
            <div class="itemWrapper categoryWebDesign">
                <a href="index.html"><img alt="" src="assets/images/11.png"></a>
                <span><p>Click To View Project</p></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid">
            <div class="itemWrapper categoryVisualIdentity">
                <a href="index.html"><img alt="" src="assets/images/me.png"></a>
                <span><p>Click To View Project</p></span>
            </div>
            <div class="itemWrapper categoryPhotography">
                <a href="index.html"><img alt="" src="assets/images/me.png"></a>
                <span><p>Click To View Project</p></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid">
            <div class="itemWrapper category-WebDesign">
                <a href="index.html"><img alt="" src="assets/images/11.png"></a>
                <span><p>Click To View Project</p></span>
            </div>
            <div class="itemWrapper category-WebDesign">
                <a href="index.html"><img alt="" src="assets/images/me.png"></a>
                <span><p>Click To View Project</p></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

```js
$('.categoryButton-All').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('portfolio-topSectionClicked'); 
    $("#portfolio-gallerySection .grid div").not(".categoryAll").fadeOut(); 
});
```

In a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4HFvx

Comment: Your fiddle seems to be missing the javascript?

Comment: I don't think what I am using now is a good option, but here is the JS i am trying to get working: `$('.categoryButton-All').click(function(){
  $(this).addClass('portfolio-topSectionClicked');
  $("#portfolio-gallerySection .grid div").not(".categoryAll").fadeOut();
 });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated your fiddle below. I supply each filter button with a "data-filter" attribute, then apply this as a class to your gallery using the following script:

```
;(function(){
    var $portfoliogallerySection = $('#portfolio-gallerySection'),
        $filterbuttons = $('#portfolio-topSection a');
    $filterbuttons.on('click', function(){
         var $this = $(this);
         $filterbuttons.removeClass('active');
         $this.addClass('active');
         $portfoliogallerySection.attr('class', $this.data('filter'));
    });
}());
```

Then use css to hide / show appropriately categorised items in the gallery, i'll leave the transitions to you.

http://jsfiddle.net/4HFvx/4/

Comment: This worked perfectly, however how would you go to add an .active class to the menu buttons when clicked / is selected?

Comment: Updated code block in the answer to toggle an active class on the appropriate button